# Как найти самую длинную строку в List?

Tags: java, массивы, arraylist

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ нахождения самой длинной строки в ArrayList.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Собссн банальный цикл и сравнение значения с предыдущем вполне спасёт:

```
ArrayList<String> Str = new ArrayList<String>();
Str.add("Jim Bob");
Str.add("Bobby Jones");
Str.add("Rob Stiles");

int largestString = Str.get(0).length();
int index = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < Str.size(); i++) {
    if(Str.get(i).length() > largestString) {
        largestString = Str.get(i).length();
        index = i;
    }
}

System.out.println("Index " + index + " "+ Str.get(index) + " " + "is the largest and is size " + largestString);
```

---

Вариант с *Java8* (использовать `java.util.Collections.max`)

```
String max = Collections.max(StrList, Comparator.comparing(s -> s.length()));
```

---

Еще вариант с *Collections*, но до *Java8*

```
String max = Collections.max(Str, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return o1.length() - o2.length();
    }
});

System.out.println(max);
```

`Collections.max` - принимает на вход коллекцию (в данном случае строк) и компаратор, в котором должна быть описана логика сравнения элементов коллекции.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++); {
        strings.add(r.readLine());
    }
    int m = strings.get(0).length();
    for (String s : strings)
    if (s.length() > m)
    m = s.length();
    for (String s : strings)
    if (s.length() == m)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Как-то вы переусложнили, достаточно одного цикла для нахождения самой длинной строки. Посмотрите первый пример в другом ответе.